# Running header with line number in reledmac/reledpar

Tags: header-footer, reledmac, reledpar

I've been typesetting a trilingual text of the Passion of st. Mark (greek, latin and spanish) with reledpar. And I would love to have a running header in every page with the chapter and verses that appear in each page spread ("Mk 14:1-5" ideally, being able to construct some logic for "Mk 14:60-15:2" and the like). Following the examples provided by reledmac, I've been able to set the left side correctly, but I can't seem to get in also on the right page. BTW, I have to use the `linunumannotation` for the critical apparatus.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[noresetlinenumannotation]{reledmac}
\usepackage[shiftedpstarts]{reledpar}

\def\sectionmark#1{}%Disable section marking

\newcounter{chap}
\setcounter{chap}{13}

\newcommand{\bc}[1]{%
    \edef\tmp{\noexpand\setcounter{chap}{#1}}%\tmp will be expanded 
    \expandafter\doinsidethislinehook\expandafter{\tmp}%First, we expand \tmp to  the value, and then, pass the result as argument to \doinsidelinehook
    {\large{\textbf{#1}}}%
}

\newcommand{\bv}[1]{\textbf{#1}\linenumannotation{#1}\doinsidethislinehook{\markboth{#1}{#1}}}

\makepagestyle{content}
\makeevenhead{content}{Mk \thechap:\rightmark - \leftmark}{}{\thepage}
\makeoddhead{content}{\thepage}{}{Mk \thechap:\rightmark-\leftmark}
\pagestyle{content}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{pages}
    \begin{Leftside}
        \beginnumbering
                
        \pstart
        \bc{14} \bv{1} First verse in Greek \bv{2} Second verse in Greek.
        \pend
        
        \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
    \begin{Rightside}
        \beginnumbering
        
        \pstart
        \bc{14} \bv{1} First verse in English. \bv{2} Second verse in English.
        \pend
    
        \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages
    
\end{document}
```

[image: compilation of mwe]